# Burn folders continuously created when a blank CD or DVD is inserted

Tags: optical-drive

I have an iMac running 10.13 and it creates burn folders continuously until I eject the disc. If I reset Preferences to ask me what to do when a blank disc is inserted, it creates Finder popups that appear and disappear continuously. Any suggestions?

Comment: So essentially, you pop in a disc and the Mac just goes crazy? I'm assuming you're inserting a blank recordable disc when this happens, and that this **doesn't** occur when you insert an already-written disc?

Comment: only when I insert a blank disc, put a movie or music disc in and it acts normal.